# Can I run Visual Studio 2013 for C++ and JScript at the same time?

Tags: c++, html, c, visual-studio-2013, jscript

I program in several languages (mostly learning a lot of different stuff all at once), and the environment I work in now is just awful.  I really like a lot of the changes to Visual Studio 2013, but I set it up in the C++ environment, but I'd also like to try their JScript functionality.  Is there a way to run an instance for C++ and one for web development?  I know I can open two instances of VS2013, but they will both be the C++ setup.

Comment: Finally, you understood that _"the environment I work in now is just awful"_. Perhaps, it's time to drop VS for something which fits your requirements better?

Comment: OK....Any recommendations?  I'm half and half linux/windows, and I've used g++, and command line programming, but I prefer VS over that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I could suggest to grab yourself, sit down, and learn one of the advanced text editors: Vim/Emacs/Sublime Text. It's going to be pretty tough, you'll spend around a year to discover what's best for you, to configure everything to the point where it satisfies all your needs, to find the plugins that you need, and etc. But as anybody who is already using one of them would say - _"this investment is worth a time"_. Of course all what I say is kind of personal opinion, but I'm not the only one who would tell you that. Vim/Emacs guys write text/code 3-4 times faster then mortals...

Comment: To wrap it up, I am experienced with all 3 of them, but my current choice is Vim. Before that I was like you: tried different IDEs one by one and was always pissed because some IDE prodives something, but another one doesn't and vice versa. Furthermore, you have to wait for IDE features for years to be added as some of them are proprietary. The merit of advanced text editors is that they are open-source and offer well-thought scripting mechanisms to be extended. But probably the most important point is that if you still touch the mouse while programming - you're not a (productive) programmer.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I'm experienced with VIM and Emacs, but not sublime, so I'll look into that.  I prefer Vim over Emacs, by a lot.  I have trouble wrapping my head around the idea of those being "advanced", or more advanced than VS at least.  When I'm on my linux machine, I always use vim, but I was hoping for a miracle IDE that somebody knew of.  I really do appreciate the response and I'll look into what you said.  Maybe you should post one of these as an answer so I can mark it as such?